# What is the difference between [image] and [image-processing]?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

We have a tag [image](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/image) and a tag [image-processing](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/image-processing). Their descriptions are quite similar:

> This tag covers signal processing where input is an image, such as a photograph or video frame and the output could be an improved or altered image, parameters related to the image or information about features within the image.

and

> In general, image processing is any form of signal processing for which the input is an image, such as a photograph or video frame.

Do we want to disambiguate these tags, or do we want to make them synonyms?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given that there are 524 questions tagged with <kbd>image</kbd> and [389 tagged with that and <kbd>image-processing</kbd> both](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/image+image-processing) I think it makes sense to create a synonym.

---

Edited to add:

[image: Output of merge operation.]

Comment: Thank you! This makes things less confusing I think.

Comment: @CrisLuengo You're welcome. Thanks for posting.